# React Sharing Data Between Components without reloading component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map component, where the user will select images and another component on the side to use the data from the selection. but, when I set context on the map component it reloads and the map to reset. - how would i block this component from reloading, or use a method to share this data without triggering reload?

[example](https://6o6bf.csb.app/) use the zoom buttons / mousewheel to see the reset issue.

I thought the way to do this is using a context component, and passing the functions as values in the provider

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
export const ImageContext = createContext(); 
export const ImageProvider = (props) => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    return <ImageContext.Provider value={[images,setImages]} >
    {props.children}
    </ImageContext.Provider>;
 };
```

wrapping my app in the `contextprovider` (the components are siblings, not child-parent relationship)

```
return (
<div id="App">
        <ImageProvider>
             ...
             <SidePanel />
              <WebMapView />
             ...
          </ImageProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I import into my `mapcomponent` the context and `Usecontext` as below

```
import { ImageContext } from "./ImageContext";
const [images, setImages] = useContext(ImageContext);
```

then setting the context as below when the user makes input to the map

```
export const WebMapView = () => {
...
    setImages(results.features);
...
}
```

#### Description of issues:

1. I need to get selection data on the map and pass it TO the `sidecomponent` each time the user makes an input without reloading the map, but keeping the normal functionality of react reloading the `sidepanel` when new data is available in the state
2. I need to pass information FROM the `sidepanel` to the `mapcomponent` to process within the map, but without reloading the map.

I start to get the impression context is not the right tool for this, should i be using something else? i have looked into shouldComponentUpdate and `purecomponents`, but the documentation states that they are more 'suggestions' and don't guarantee preventing a reload...